# My custom user controls get this hresult_not_implemented {} in XamlSystemBaseType::IsConstructible()

Tags: uwp, c++-cx, c++-winrt

My custom user controls get this weird error message. Why does it even get here

```
bool ::XamlTypeInfo::InfoProvider::XamlSystemBaseType::IsConstructible::get()
{
   throw ref new ::Platform::NotImplementedException;
}
```

I have two DLLs - one developed with CX and one with cppwinrt. I sent the wrong code fragment. My main app is in cppwinrt. The problem occurs even in cppwinrt at this junction:

```
bool XamlSystemBaseType::IsConstructible() const
{
    throw ::winrt::hresult_not_implemented {};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you asked the same question on the C++/WinRT marketplace. But without knowing more about your project we can't really help. Any chance you could share a simple project that shows the problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce in a simple project. I get these random at run time at start up. Some launches in works and some others it doesn't. cppwinrt gets confused on meta data generation when you have a non-simple situation - one app, multiple winrt DLLs. Case in point I use  3 cppwinrt DLLs that reference Win2D. The meta data generators produce duplicate winmerge's. for example.

Comment: In XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp, typeName = 'VideoApp.CustomMTC' is my custom user control
baseName = 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.UserControl'                                   CreateXamlType(hstring const& typeName)
{
    ....
    else
    {
        hstring baseName { pTypeInfo->baseTypeIndex >= 0 ? TypeInfos[pTypeInfo->baseTypeIndex].typeName : L""};
        hstring boxedName { pTypeInfo->boxedTypeIndex >= 0 ? TypeInfos[pTypeInfo->boxedTypeIndex].typeName : L""};
        auto userType = make_self<XamlUserType>(shared_from_this(), pTypeInfo->typeName, GetXamlTypeByName(baseName));
    }
}

Comment: XamlSystemBaseType::IsConstructible should never be called. That object is what we call a "system" type which is known by the XAML framework. The framework would never call to app metadata for those types. Can you trace the call stack and see who's calling into those? XamlUserType::IsConstructible has an implementation and will be called by the framework.

Comment: WinDx.UI.Xaml.dll!winrt::WinDx::UI::Xaml::implementation::XamlSystemBaseType::IsConstructible() Line 210 C++
  WinDx.UI.Xaml.dll!winrt::impl::produce<winrt::WinDx::UI::Xaml::implementation::XamlSystemBaseType,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Markup::IXamlType>::get_IsConstructible(bool * value) Line 1110 C++
  VideoApp.exe!winrt::impl::consume_Windows_UI_Xaml_Markup_IXamlType<winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Markup::IXamlType>::IsConstructible() Line 322 C++
  VideoApp.exe!winrt::VideoApp::implementation::XamlTypeInfoProvider::CheckOtherMetadataProvidersForName(const winrt::hstring & typeName) Line 137

Comment: ... implementation::XamlTypeInfoProvider::GetXamlTypeByName(const winrt::hstring & typeName) Line 90 C++
  ... implementation::XamlTypeInfoProvider::CreateXamlType(const winrt::hstring & typeName) Line 1963 C++
  ... implementation::XamlTypeInfoProvider::GetXamlTypeByName(const winrt::hstring & typeName) Line 86 C++

Comment: ... implementation::XamlMetaDataProvider::GetXamlType(const winrt::hstring & fullName) Line 32 C++
  ... implementation::AppT<winrt::VideoApp::implementation::App>::GetXamlType(const winrt::hstring & fullName) Line 33 C++
  VideoApp.exe!winrt::impl::produce<winrt::VideoApp::implementation::App,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Markup::IXamlMetadataProvider>::GetXamlTypeByFullName(void * fullName, void * * result) Line 983 C++

Comment: I split the stack track into 3 comments